# BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero when performing RSA encryption of session key

Tags: java, encryption

I have this part of RSA decryption code :

```
// Turn the encoded key into a real RSA private key.
// Private keys are encoded in PKCS#8.
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

// Create a cipher using that key to initialize it
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

// Read in the encrypted bytes of the session key
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileInput));
byte[] encryptedKeyBytes = new byte[dis.readInt()];
dis.readFully(encryptedKeyBytes);

// Decrypt the session key bytes.
rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] rijndaelKeyBytes = rsaCipher.doFinal(encryptedKeyBytes);

// Transform the key bytes into an actual key.
SecretKey rijndaelKey = new SecretKeySpec(rijndaelKeyBytes, "Rijndael");
```

An error appears when I choose the private key file and I encrypt it by the session key to do the asymmetric encryption of the principal file :

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please use a spell checker and reread your question before posting. Make sure to use well used tags. [tag:cipher] is hardly used, use [tag:encryption] or [tag:cryptography] instead - if you don't your question may not be noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question shows that there is some misunderstanding:

> An error appears when I choose the private key file and I encrypt it by the session key to do the asymmetric encryption of the principal file :

So the above code decrypts the *session key* using the *RSA private key*. Then the session key can be used to decrypt the data. So you need to encrypt the data with a new random session key, then encrypt the *session key* using the *RSA public key*.

You should in general never encrypt an RSA private key for any other entity. RSA private keys should stay private. You only encrypt them for backup or protection within key storage.

Comment: Anything missing from my answer, user3077162?